# Find Min Value of All Rows Within One CSV and Print All to New File in Python

Tags: python, csv, min

I have a folder filled with csv files and each file looks something like this:

```
TPN,201203,by the congress,3,0.000001559523908541200542298447130
TPN,201312,by the congress,2,0.000001975728179317089554819047995
TPN,201308,by the congress,2,0.000002130556224313481520620588417
CR,200910,by the congress,10,0.000001254229103759238181242376639
CR,200911,by the congress,5,6.974221464170843876612631794E-7
MED,200507,by the congress,2,0.000004113271264069958517659301854
```

I want a script that goes through each file and finds the minimum date value in that file and then prints every line in that file that includes that date value into a new file (so if two rows have the same date value it should print both). I have this:

```
import csv
import os
import codecs 
import unicodecsv

folder = '/Users/xyz/Desktop/TextAnalysis/PointsOfOrigin/trigramsdated/'

c = csv.writer(open("trigrampointsoforigin.csv", "a"))

for file in os.listdir (folder):
    with open(os.path.join(folder, file), mode='rU') as f:
        m=min(int(line[1]) for line in unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace'))
        f.seek(0)
        for line in unicodecsv.reader(f):
            if int(line[1])==m:
                print line
                c.writerow(line)

print "All done."
```

But for some weird reason, it just consistently prints the last line in each csv to the "trigramspointsoforign.csv" file.

Any help is much, much appreciated.

Comment: *"and each file looks something like this:"*??

Comment: Oops! Thanks @AshwiniChaudhary , I've added the sample file.

Comment: If it is only writing the last line then perhaps `c.writerow(line)` is not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Does `line[1]` actually print out the date value?  In any case, you can avoid one of your inner loops:

```
for file in os.listdir (folder):
    with open(os.path.join(folder, file), mode='rU') as f:
        minline = [-1,-1] # Some min value
        for linenum, line in enumerate(unicodecsv.reader(f)):
            if int(line[1]) < int(minline[1]):
                # Replace with new minline
                minline = copy.copy(line) 
        print minline
        c.writerow(minline)
```

You will need to `import copy`.